# Python PyLandStats available metric keyword arguments

Tags: python

I am working with the Python package PyLandStats. I am attempting to set keyword arguments, but it seems the documentation is lacking a full list of available arguments. Could someone point me in the direction of where I could find all the available `metrics_kws` in the PyLandStats package?

In the [documentation](https://pylandstats.readthedocs.io/en/latest/landscape.html), it refers to keyword arguments `metrics_kws` that can be specified to change how measures are calculated. There are two examples provided in the documentation, but in an example [Jupyter notebook](https://github.com/martibosch/pylandstats-notebooks/blob/main/notebooks/03-zonal-analysis.ipynb), there is a third keyword that wasn't shown in the documentation. This causes me to think that there are others that may not be presented in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It can appear a bit confusing, but `metrics_kws` can be any mapping of the method to compute a metric (e.g., `perimeter_area_ratio`) to its keyword arguments (e.g., a dictionary of the form `{"hectares": True}`). Altogether, this would be:

```
metrics_kws = {"perimeter_area_ratio": {"hectares": True}}
```

Note that when you are computing metrics using methods such as `compute_class_metrics_df` or `compute_landscape_metrics_df`, the `class_val` argument of each metric' method is already taken care of. Therefore, you should only specify keyword arguments other than `class_val` (e.g., `hectares`, percent`,` count_boundary`...). You can see a list of metrics and their respective keyword arguments at [the pylandstats documentation](https://pylandstats.readthedocs.io/en/latest/landscape.html#list-of-implemented-metrics).